# How to open lightbox on page load only once

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a lightbox on my home page only once when page load and not again when i refresh the page. 
i m a newbie javascript

Comment: Only once as in, only once while the browser is open (session) or only once to each browser in a computer? Either way you'll be using session/localStorage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a cookie, either with session or longer scope. The internet has tons of samples on how to access/set cookie values: [For example](http://www.cookiecentral.com/demomain.htm).